# Can't install prebuilt gem

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, pg

I'm trying to install prebuilt binary of `pg` gem on windows (I don't want devkit):

```
>ruby -v
ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x64-mingw32]

>gem install pg
Fetching: pg-0.17.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        The 'pg' native gem requires installed build tools.

>gem install pg -v 0.17.1 --platform=x64-mingw32
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        The 'pg' native gem requires installed build tools.
```

even though the binary gem is published at https://rubygems.org/gems/pg/versions/0.17.1-x64-mingw32

What am I doing wrong ?

Same thing happens with 32-bit ruby.

Comment: Are you sure that's pre-built? Normally the ones published directly on rubygems.org are not, at least as far as I've understood it. I'd always thought it was up to other distribution methods to provide that type, like Homebrew, Apt, or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the gem was prebuilt for ruby 2.0.x which is not ABI compatible with ruby 2.1.x that I'm using. The error message could be more clear about that :(

Switched to the latest pre-release that contains needed binary and everything is fine now.